# Data Aggregation in Excel

Tags: excel, data-structures

Suppose Bill Gates owns a fund that in turn owns a fund that in turn own Microsoft Shares. In the financial market this is very common, this could go even further (x owns y that owns z, that owns...). The problem is, how to retrieve data from the last node to the first node recursively? That is, how to know how many shares of Microsoft Bill Gates owns?  In SQL one could use JOIN and then try some hack after it, but even then it would only show that Bill owns a fund. The final connection, that is, one of Bills funds owns Microsoft Shares wouldn't be connect(it would show that y belongs to x, but this information wouldn't be connected to y belongs to z). So, what's the best approach to solve this in excel? I'm totally opened to suggestions like 'it's better to convert it to csv and then try this suggested SQL command'. Below is a diagram for better understanding the problem.[image]

Here's a diagram for even better understanding:
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution?

Comment: I'm kinda lost @JohnColeman, so any solution is welcome. I can handle any language.

Comment: Just to say something about SQL since you mentioned it, you would use a recursive CTE and it would very simple to do this. (looking at the excel now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is kind of a wild idea inspired by your diagram. Create the following seemingly pointless function in VBA:

```
Function Owns(Owner As String, ParamArray assets() As Variant) As String
    Owns = Owner
End Function
```

The -- write a macro to replace the strings in column A by formulas according to the logic shown by:

[image]

(Obviously -- only the formulas in A2-A6 are entered - the text in A8-A12 is just my commentary). To get these, loop through column A -- see what they own by scanning over to column C. If the string in column C is also in Column A -- put all column A (but no column C) references to that asset as arguments to Owns(). This applies to the first three entries in column A. If the asset is only in Column C - put the reference to column C for that row. This applies to the last two entries in A.

Why would you want to do that?. Well - select the cell containing Bill Gates, go over to the Formula tab, and repeatedly invoke `Trace Precedents`. You should see:

[image]

Punchline: VBA Range objects have a method `.Precedents()` which give these cells as a range object. The precedent cells in column C are the leaves of the precedent tree. There is also a method `.DirectPrecedents()` which can be used to process the tree level by level. Whether or not it is helpful in this case I honestly don't know, but it does seem like a nice way to get a tree-like structure for your data which can be manipulated in VBA.

On edit: Tracing dependents can get you back from say T-Bonds to Bill Gates. There are two VBA methods which correspond to that. Furthermore, there are methods like `.ShowPrecedents` which can be used to animate the arrows to allow a user to see the flow of dependents. I've also experimented with a method (using a second dummy function in some cells in C) that will have cells in column A directly linked to cells in column C which in turn are linked to cells in column A in a way that the `ShowPrecedents` will display the back and forth flow of the data -- but I think this would add superfluous levels to the tree.

I wrote a macro which takes a spreadsheet set up like the original ones and adds the dummy formulas. To use it you need to

1) Create two named ranges. "Owner" which is the column of owner names (A2:A6 in this toy example) and "Asset" which is the corresponding part of the asset column (C2:C6 here).

2) Include a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Tools/References in the VBA editor) so that dictionaries can be used.

For completeness sake I am adding the code for "owns" again as well as a sub called "restore" that will replace the added formulas by the strings that are displayed (which should be the original strings):

Function Owns(Owner As String, ParamArray assets() As Variant) As String
    Owns = Owner
End Function

```
Sub tag()
    Dim Owner As Range, Asset As Range
    Dim OwnerAddress As New Dictionary
    Dim OwnerFormula As New Dictionary
    Dim OwnerRange As Range
    Dim ocell As Range, acell As Range
    Dim owner_name As Variant, asset_name As String
    Dim formula As String
    Dim shift As Long

    Set Owner = Range("Owner")
    Set Asset = Range("Asset")
    shift = Asset.Column - Owner.Column '2 now, but user might move columns around

    For Each ocell In Owner
        owner_name = LCase(Trim(ocell.Value))
        If OwnerAddress.Exists(owner_name) Then
            OwnerAddress(owner_name) = OwnerAddress(owner_name) & ", " & ocell.Address
        Else
            OwnerAddress(owner_name) = ocell.Address
        End If
    Next ocell

    For Each owner_name In OwnerAddress.Keys
        Set OwnerRange = Range(OwnerAddress(owner_name)) 'e.g. all ocells containing "Bill's Fund"
        formula = "=Owns(" & """" & OwnerRange.Cells(1).Value & """"
        For Each ocell In OwnerRange
            Set acell = ocell.Offset(0, shift)
            asset_name = LCase(Trim(acell.Value))
            If OwnerAddress.Exists(asset_name) Then
                formula = formula & "," & OwnerAddress(asset_name)
            Else
                formula = formula & "," & acell.Address
            End If
        Next ocell
        formula = formula & ")"
        OwnerFormula.Add owner_name, formula
    Next owner_name

    For Each ocell In Owner
        ocell.formula = OwnerFormula(LCase(Trim(ocell.Value)))
    Next ocell
End Sub
```

Comment: you are my hero!!!! That was so clever of yours, i would never thought of using precedents in that manner! That's exactly the relation i would like to see.. THANK YOU